# Automatically turning on a feature on a new site collection

Tags: 2010, site-collection

Is it possible to turn on a custom feature atomically when you create a new site collection? I have a branding feature that I want to be turned on by default for each site collection made.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For now, SharePoint 2010 does not support event for site collection *adding* or *added*.So it is not possible to do it programmatically

Yes, You can plugin your feature to the site definition used for the site collection by "Feature Stapling".

You can define a feature at scope of Web application. It will automatically activate the stapled feature(which is your feature) within every site (in web application) that is based on the site definition you provide in *<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation>* like below sample.

If you want to activate the feature for all kind of sites in web application, you can
associate stapling a feature to global site definition(TemplateName=" GLOBAL") and blank site (TemplateName=" STS#1").

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation   
Id="edcdcd75-dff2-479d-ac32-b37f8fa9d459"
TemplateName=" GLOBAL" />
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation   
Id="edcdcd75-dff2-479d-ac32-b37f8fa9d459"
TemplateName=" STS#1" />
</Elements>
```

Change the Id to your feature Id in above sample.

The scope of the feature that does the stapling must be higher than the features
being stapled. For example, a feature at the site collection scope can staple
only features at site-level scope. So, you can fine tune the your feature scope accordingly

Comment: As our moderator Anders remembered me in another post, be carefull that some site definitions may use the *"[AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spwebtemplate.allowglobalfeatureassociations.aspx)"* in which case they will be excluded from GLOBAL stapling. If you are using any of such definition (for example the Blank Site - STS#1) be sure to include them explicitly.

Comment: Yes, It is off for STS#1 that's why I included explicitly in the above example

Comment: Right, I added that comment only for readability sake (other custom templates could use the "AllowGlobalFeatureAssociations" so it always better to doublecheck that option if some issues emerges). I had already assumed that you knew that from you post.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible. The (probably) easiest way is to use [feature stapling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kunal_mukherjee/archive/2011/01/11/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx). Then you can say that all new instances of e.g. STS#0 (Team site), should activate this feature.

```
<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="b8f334a0-1ffe-420d-b6e2-54a9faa6ba95" TemplateName="STS#0" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a a Feature of Web Application Scope and deploy it on your Web Application. So whenever you will create a site collection in your web app, that feature will be activated on it.

You can also set the Automatic Activate property of the Feature to TRUE.

Comment: Sadly the scope of the feature Iwant turned on can only be site and lower as I need to put files in the MasterPageGallery

Comment: John, the feature would live at the Web Application level, but applied to anything under it (ie: site or web). The feature would have to be one layer above what you wanted to detect creation of.